# Python OS mkdir (create folders with looping a list)

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to create folders using os.mkdir with looping over a list for example i want 12 folders with names of months, January, February ...etc.

```
import os

months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",    "September", "October", "November", "December"]

for month in months:
    os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS')
```

with many lines like this i could create the folders i wanted

```
import os
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Jan')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Feb')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Mar')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Apr')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\May')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Jun')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\July')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Aug')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Sep')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Oct')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Nov')
os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\Dec')
```

But is there any way to do it with looping.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a prime job for `os.path.join()` which joins its arguments by the system's separator.  Its also a great way to cut down on `\` related errors.

```
baseDir = "D:\\Python_GIS"

for month in months:
    os.makedir(os.path.join(baseDir,month))
```

Unrelated style note: Try setting your paths as raw strings which will ignore literals, so `baseDir = r'D:\Python_GIS'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format` :

```
for month in months:
    os.mkdir('D:\\Python_GIS\\{}'.format(month))
```